# Integrate Vue.js with laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-routing, vue-router

I have built my static design using vue.js. Now, I need to integrate it within Laravel. 
Once I do integrate Laravel with Vue then Laravel is not getting the Design files path. I mean the various Style and JS files.

FYI, I build the Vue in static design and it was working fine before integration with Laravel. But, while integrating with Laravel I am no longer using the build or build.js file. Instead of this, I am building using Laravel ways.

The main issue is the design is broken and the route is not working.

Comment: first, try to open the web with browser inspect/dev tools, check out there are any 404 error on loading the js files. you may need to find out the right path.

Comment: I did not integrated the build.js which made by vue.
Instead of this, I'm using Laravel build process. 
I suspect the Import files are missing there. How could I get the all vue required file using laravel build?

Comment: you may need to study webpack
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mix#custom-webpack-configuration

Comment: Thanks but the problem is integrating Vue with Laravel

Comment: "Thanks but the problem..."  No you **do need to look at Webpack / Laravel Mix** , that is the integration.  In a standard Laravel project Vue is already integrated out of the box.  No need to re invent the wheel here.  READ THE DOCUMENTATION  there is a full guide about Vue as a frontend right there. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/frontend

Comment: I build my static site using vue. Now I need to Integrate this sttaic site with laravel. Once I am trying to integrating it, pages are coming as broken.